# Ruby regex to convert uppercased words and keep titleized ones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, gsub

Given string "Lorem IPSUM dolor Sit amet". Capital letters in "Lorem" and "Sit" should be kept, uppercased ones like "IPSUM" should be converted to "Ipsum"

How to make "Lorem Ipsum dolor Sit amet" from given string using gsub?
NOT working example: `s.gsub(/[[:upper:]]/){$&.downcase}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`capitalize`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize) with `/\b[[:upper:]]{2,}\b/` regex:

```
s.gsub(/\b[[:upper:]]{2,}\b/){$&.capitalize}
# => Lorem Ipsum dolor Sit amet
```

See the [online Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/7l687k).

Note that the `\b[[:upper:]]{2,}\b` pattern will match whole words (as `\b` are word boundaries) that only consist of 2 or more uppercase letters (there seems no need to match words like `I` that are already OK).

Comment: BTW, it is also possible to use `\b[[:upper:]]{2,}\b` to match words with 2 or more uppercase  letters since `I` is already OK. I updated the answer.